# Direct2D Custom Effect RegisterEffectFromString doesn't work

Tags: c++, direct2d

This is my code snippet:

```
#include <initguid.h>
DEFINE_GUID(CLSID_SimpleTriangleEffect, 0xef88e1e3, 0x3204, 0x4f56, 0x94, 0x98, 0x8a, 0xa6, 0xa4, 0x4b, 0xbb, 0x93);
```

```
PCWSTR pszXml =
        XML(
            < ? xml version = '1.0' ? >
            <Effect>
            <Property name = 'DisplayName' type = 'string' value = 'SimpleTriangleEffect' / >
            <Property name = 'Author'      type = 'string' value = 'Charles Petzold' / >
            <Property name = 'Category'    type = 'string' value = 'Sample' / >
            <Property name = 'Description' type = 'string' value = 'Applies simple effect' / >
            <Inputs>
            < / Inputs>
            < / Effect>
        );

    HRESULT hr = pFactory->RegisterEffectFromString(CLSID_SimpleTriangleEffect,
        pszXml,
        nullptr,
        0,
        SimpleTriangleEffect::Create);
```

`CLSID_SimpleTriangleEffect` does not register.

And returns `hr = 0xc00cee61`, which isn't described in the function's documentation. As far as I could gather is an *Error in Measure* but I don't know how and where. I don't even know where to search for the bug.

Comment: this is a code copied from the "Three Triangles" code found here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2014/july/directx-factor-breaking-the-z-barrier-with-direct2d-effects

Comment: 0xc00cee61 is an XmlLite error: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/ms753129(v=vs.85) your XML is incorrect. You have extra spaces all around

Comment: so what is wrong with the XML? what does "NC_E_QNAMECHARACTER" means? is there something wrong with my XML? I can't see anything wrong with what I included...this is the only place XML is used or referenced in the code

Comment: Like I say, you have two spaces e.g: ` < / Inputs>` shouldbe `  </Inputs>` etc.

Comment: thanks for the clarification. didn't notice that... I copied this code As-Is and thought that it should be that way. I didn't use XML in VS before and rarely ever used XML in general.